# Changing number of rows of tabs visible in NetBeans

Tags: netbeans, user-interface

There are times when I have a decent number of source files open at once. Is there a way to change the number of rows of tabs that are visible while working in NetBeans?

Also, I have a dual monitor setup here. I could span NetBeans across the two monitors if it were possible to have multiple NetBeans editor windows open at the same time. This is something that I use in the VS Express editions. I tend to group my source files on one monitor and the designer windows in the other. Can I do this in NetBeans?

Comment: What do you mean by the number of rows of tabs? I'm having a hard time picturing it.

Comment: Imagine like the applications list in the tray on Windows XP, imagine each app is instead a tab like one in Firefox but you can expand the height of the tray/tabs area so the tabs carry on in the next row.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 2 way's I have done this:

- Drag a tab from the editor panel to the side of the editor window until the red outline shows a rectangle running from top to bottom. Drop the tab there and you get another editor pane. Opening from Project or Files will still use the original panel, but you can drag tabs between the panels.
- Right click on a tab and choose "Undock Window". This will create a top-level window independent of the main NB window.

When you create files with keyboard shortcuts (eg, Ctrl-N for new file) they will open in the current panel. Likewise, navigating to other files (eg, Ctrl-Shift-B for go to source).

It's not perfect though. Some keyboard actions will dump you back to the main window, then it's Alt-Tab or fiddle with the mouse to get back.

Answer (score 22):

for versions 8.0.2+:

`Tools -> Options -> Appearance -> Document Tabs -> Multi-row tabs`

You can also maximum row count if you wish (the default is 3).

Answer (score 4):

You can control the number of rows of Tabs in Netbeans by going to (on Windows):

Tools>Options>Miscellaneous>Windows> check the multi-row tabs checkbox.

See the maximum row count with the radio button and set your number.

Comment: There ain't no "Tools>Options>Miscellaneous>Windows" in NB currently (8.0.2), see http://stackoverflow.com/a/27554434/719662